# How to reduce padding between bars in grouped bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've a grouped bar chart based on `D3`. Is there a way I can reduce the gap between bars in each group and not between the groups. I've a fixed width for each bar.

Snippet as follows:

```js
//DATA
var data = [
  {
    category: "test4",
    type1: 100,
    type2: 200,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test4",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 500,
    column: "column2"
  },
  {
    category: "test3",
    type1: 100,
    type2: 200,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test3",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 500,
    column: "column2"
  },
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 100,
    type2: 200,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 500,
    column: "column2"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 150,
    type2: 100,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 400,
    column: "column2"
  }
];

var groupData = d3
  .nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.column + d.category;
  })
  .rollup(function(v) {
    return {
      ...v[0],
      total: v[0].type1 + v[0].type2 + v[0].type3
    };
  })
  .entries(data)
  .map(function(d) {
    return { ...d.value };
  });


//INITIAL SETUP
var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 40 };
var width = groupData.length * 80 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var barwidth = 40;

var tip = d3
  .tip()
  .attr("class", "d3-tip")
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<span>Test</span>";
  });

var graph = d3
  .select("#chart-area")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

graph.call(tip);

var x0 = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var y1 = d3.scaleBand();

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);

var stack = d3.stack();

x0.domain(
  data.map(function(d) {
    return d.category;
  })
);
x1
  .domain(
    data.map(function(d) {
      return d.column;
    })
  )
  .range([0, x0.bandwidth()])
  .padding(0.2);

z.domain(Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => x !== "category" && x !== "column"));
var keys = z.domain(); //["type1", "type2", "type3"];

var stackData = stack.keys(keys)(groupData);

y.domain([
  0,
  d3.max(groupData, function(d) {
    return d.total;
  })
]);
var serie = graph
  .selectAll(".serie")
  .data(stackData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "serie")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return z(d.key);
  });

serie
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "serie-rect")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.data.category) + ",0)";
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.data.column) + x1.bandwidth() / 2 - 20;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", barwidth)
  .on("mouseover", tip.show)
  .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"));
```

```css
#chart-area {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-area"></div>
```

Comment: don't hard code your bar width, use the `padding` option of `scaleBand`

Comment: @rioV8. I need the bar width to be 40 and it's bad but, it's a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `paddingOuter` in the innerScale. For instance:

```
x1.paddingOuter(0.5);
```

Here is the code with that change.

```js
//DATA
var data = [
  {
    category: "test4",
    type1: 100,
    type2: 200,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test4",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 500,
    column: "column2"
  },
  {
    category: "test3",
    type1: 100,
    type2: 200,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test3",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 500,
    column: "column2"
  },
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 100,
    type2: 200,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 500,
    column: "column2"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 150,
    type2: 100,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 400,
    column: "column2"
  }
];

var groupData = d3
  .nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.column + d.category;
  })
  .rollup(function(v) {
    return {
      ...v[0],
      total: v[0].type1 + v[0].type2 + v[0].type3
    };
  })
  .entries(data)
  .map(function(d) {
    return { ...d.value };
  });


//INITIAL SETUP
var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 40 };
var width = groupData.length * 80 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var barwidth = 40;

var tip = d3
  .tip()
  .attr("class", "d3-tip")
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<span>Test</span>";
  });

var graph = d3
  .select("#chart-area")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

graph.call(tip);

var x0 = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var y1 = d3.scaleBand();

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);

var stack = d3.stack();

x0.domain(
  data.map(function(d) {
    return d.category;
  })
);
x1
  .domain(
    data.map(function(d) {
      return d.column;
    })
  )
  .range([0, x0.bandwidth()])
  .paddingOuter(0.5);

z.domain(Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => x !== "category" && x !== "column"));
var keys = z.domain(); //["type1", "type2", "type3"];

var stackData = stack.keys(keys)(groupData);

y.domain([
  0,
  d3.max(groupData, function(d) {
    return d.total;
  })
]);
var serie = graph
  .selectAll(".serie")
  .data(stackData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "serie")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return z(d.key);
  });

serie
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "serie-rect")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.data.category) + ",0)";
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.data.column) + x1.bandwidth() / 2 - 20;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", barwidth)
  .on("mouseover", tip.show)
  .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"));
```

```css
#chart-area {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-area"></div>
```

As you can see, this will simultaneously reduce the distance between the grouped bars and increase the distance among the groups (because, obviously, I'm not changing the range of the outer scale). Also, not related to your question: you're overwriting the padding in the inner scale.

Comment: When there is only one group. The bars are overlapping.

Comment: If there is just one group it's not a grouped bar chart. Therefore, it's another problem, requiring another solution.